# How to get rid of header?

Tags: python, pycharm

So I have been using pycharm and I noticed at the top that it says logger.pyw which is a project I worked on a while ago. When I reopen pycharm it still stays there.[Here it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHMlk.png) How can I get rid of it? Sorry, very new to pycharm, switched from atom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings, uncheck "Reopen projects on startup".

Then it will open with a list of projects, and you can click on one to open it.